# Am in mutating the state in this reducer?

Tags: redux, immutability, react-redux

I've been reading about different methods to avoid mutating the state. One of those methods is using spread operators (...) and one of the methods to avoid using is push. However in my reducer I need to add an item to an array inside a nested structure , I couldn´t implement concat correctly so I tried the following code:

```
export default function (state=[],action){
 if (action.type === 'SELECTED_DROP') {   
     let updated = [ ...state];
     updated[action.payload.queryIndex].items.push(action.payload.item) ;   
     return updated; 
  }
return state;
}
```

So, I am using both: spread operator and push. Am I mutating the state?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are mutating the state. From what I gather your state is an array with objects containing a property items which is also an array. You are modifying the items array and so you are mutating the state.

Here's what you should do:

```
export default function (state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECTED_DROP':
      return state.map((item,ix) =>
        ix===action.payload.queryIndex ?
          {...item, items:[...item.items, action.payload.item]} :
          item
      );
    case default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The map function basically returns the old item if not changed or a new item with a new items array if it's the correct index.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you absolutely are.  You're making a shallow copy of the top-level array, but directly mutating the inner array.

There are two basic rules of immutably updating data:

- Every level of nesting needs to have a copy made
- You can use mutation, but *only* if you're mutating the actual copy

In this case, you need to make copies of the top array, the item at that index, *and* the `items` array itself.  Nested updates can get kind of ugly, but that's the way it is.

I have links to a number of articles on how to properly write immutable update code at [react-redux-links](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md), and links to a number of utility libraries for abstracting out those updates at [react-redux-links & Immutable Update Utilities](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities) .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll check those libraries . Working with nested state is  painfull.